Java MongoDB not mapping extended classes
I have a base class Person and 2 classes that extends from it. When I insert instances of these classes into the database, it keeps all the info about the extended classes as shown below.
Below is the mongo config, code used to insert, get and remove the documents as well as the classes I am trying to map to.
people.json:
[
    {
        "_id": "d54d1113-2e00-46ef-8128-c6bc42220a6f",
        "name": "Jo",
        "_class": "person"
    },
    {
        "_id": "3187d2a6-08da-4055-9080-2bfb7481a4a2",
        "name": "Josh",
        "jobTitle": "Manager",
        "_class": "employee"
    },
    {
        "_id": "80c25ae9-a402-469c-9873-5c093e093733",
        "name": "John",
        "major": "Art",
        "_class": "student"
    },
]

However, when I grab the documents from the database, it only maps to the base Person class, losing the major and jobTitle field. I have tried adding a type alias to the classes, but it did not change anything.
MongoConfig.java:
package com.example.demo;

import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/example");
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();

        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }


}

Test.java:
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    MongoConfig config;

    MongoTemplate template;

    String collection = "people";

    private void insertData() {
        List<Person> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();
        peopleList.add(new Person("Jo"));
        peopleList.add(new Employee("Josh", "Manager"));
        peopleList.add(new Student("John","Art"));

        MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(config.mongoClient(), "test");
        if (template.count(new Query(), collection) == 0) {
            template.insert(peopleList, collection);
        }

    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void doStuff() {

        template = new MongoTemplate(config.mongoClient(), "test");
        insertData();
        List<Person> people = template.find(new Query(), Person.class,collection);
         template.find(new Query(), Person.class,collection);
        for (Person person : people) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }

        template.remove(new Query(),Person.class,collection);
    }
}

Person.java:
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.UUID;

@TypeAlias("person")
@Document(collection = "person")
public class Person {
    String id;
    String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

Employee.java:
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@TypeAlias("employee")
@Document(collection = "person")
public class Employee extends Person{
    String jobTitle;

    public Employee(){

    }

    public Employee(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public Employee(String name, String jobTitle) {
        super(name);
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "jobTitle='" + jobTitle + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

Student.java:
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@TypeAlias("student")
@Document(collection = "person")
public class Student extends Person {
    String major;




    public Student(String name, String major) {
        super(name);
        this.major = major;
    }

    public String getMajor() {
        return major;
    }

    public void setMajor(String major) {
        this.major = major;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "major='" + major + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

EDIT
Noticed I put the wrong class in for Test.java. Corrected it so people can see the test.

Spring Data MongoDB should be able to distinguish between the different types stored in the collection. This is typically handled by the _class field.
you should add this is your mongo config to ensure it correctly scans for the entities and handles polymorphic type mapping
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/example");
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();

        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter(MongoMappingContext context) {
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(mongoDbFactory(), context);
        converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper("_class"));
        return converter;
    }
}

I assume you have set up your service layer and repository layer correctly to fetch data from Mongo.

I've tried adding the mappingMongoConverter as you suggested however when I debug it, the function never seems to get called.
